# I have a website using static hosting on S3. It loads in a files from another directory not in S3 bucket... how?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

so I have this site, if you run it it loads in all of these files referenced in a path like this below

/Users/username/Projects/projectname/projectname-web/node_modules/ng-notifications-bar/src/ngNotificationsBar.js

none of these files are in the S3 bucket.... how do I access those files or find out where they are.  The only way I can access now is through chrome dev tools.

This company left my new client in the dark her stuff is on AWS, she has her account and access to her account but left ec2 instances running with no access keypairs assigned to it, just a pain to go in blindly.

Comment: Can you show a chunk of the HTML - are the files loading from the `file://` protocol?  Do you have an environment where you can access other users home directories from multiple machine?

Comment: as far as iI can tell it does not... and I didn't think think s3 buckets were connected to any kind of path like that

Comment: You're correct - S3 buckets are not tied like that.  So can you elaborate a bit on where you're seeing the full path name?

Comment: Ok in the app.js file in the bucket references those files.  It seems like it shouldn't work but when I load up the site through the browser and open up Chrome Dev tools it's loading in all of those files that I can see and see the source from that path that doesn't seem to exist.